# Отключение режима для чтения на iOS

Tags: html, ios

Я начинающий верстальщик на HTML.
И заметил, что почти все проекты, когда я открываю их на iPhone автоматически открывают режим для чтения.
Кто сталкивался и может помочь?
Заранее спасибо.

вот один из примеров:
https://toindiana.github.io/project_cinema/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте настройки Safari на iPhone

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]